# Is it cheating to stratified sample the whole dataset based on a previous evaluation result?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I trained a model using a small mri dataset(57 patients).
The model's performance was so low(Train set 0.7, Val set 0.7, Test set 0.45).

I found the model segment tumor in upper part of brain well, couldn't segment tumor which is in middle part of brain.

So i stratified sampled the whole dataset with a position stratum(upper, not upper), the model performance was improved.

In this case, is it cheating to do that?

Answer (score 0):

By having seen the results on the held-out test set, learning something and applying that to the model, you have essentially added some bias to your model. So if we are being strict, yes... You cheated a little bit  ;)

Without having a solid (meaning ***unbiased***) validation metric, you cannot objectively compare the two results. You used prior information to make an improved modelling decision, which is great :)   However, that information flowed directly from your test data, which introduced the bias.

It can be difficult when you have limited data, I know. You could maybe look into data augmentation to synthetically increase your dataset. In your case, adding random rotations and mirrored images could help a great deal!